# Javascript: Object method - why do I need parentheses?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and Ive stumbled upon issue that I do not understand. Could somebody explain to me why in method compareDNA I need to use parentheses while using this.dna and in the previous method it works just fine?

```js
// Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
  const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G'];
  return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
};

// Returns a random single stand of DNA containing 15 bases
const mockUpStrand = () => {
  const newStrand = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    newStrand.push(returnRandBase());
  }
  return newStrand;
};

function pAequorFactory(specimenNum, dna){
  return {
    specimenNum,
    dna,
    mutate(){
      let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)
      let newGene = returnRandBase()
      while (this.dna[i] === newGene){
        newGene = returnRandBase()
      }
      this.dna[i] = newGene
      return this.dna
    },

    compareDNA(object){
      let counter = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < this.dna().length; i++){
        if(this.dna()[i] === object.dna()[i]){
          counter++
        }
      }
      let percentage = counter / this.dna().length * 100
      return `Specimen number ${this.specimenNum} and specimen number ${object.specimenNum} have ${percentage}% of DNA in common.`
      },
    }
  }

let aligator = pAequorFactory(1, mockUpStrand)
let dog = pAequorFactory(2, mockUpStrand)
console.log(aligator.compareDNA(dog))

console.log(dog.dna().length)
```

Comment: `dna` without `()` is a **reference** to a function; followed by `()`, it indicates that you want to **call** the function. Which you use depends on what you're doing, and in general it makes the difference between code working and not working.

Comment: To me, it looks like the original author is mixed up about whether `dna` is a function returning an array or an array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `dna` that is passed as an argument is a function, so it becomes a method of the returned object, and needs to be called with `.dna()`. However, this looks like a mistake - actually an array should have been passed:

```
let aligator = pAequorFactory(1, mockUpStrand())
//                                           ^^
let dog = pAequorFactory(2, mockUpStrand())
//                                      ^^
```

Then you can access `.dna[i]` or `.dna.length` as normal.

If you don't do that, `dog.dna()` returns a different DNA every time, which doesn't make sense.

> using `this.dna` and in the previous method it works just fine?

Actually, it doesn't. `dog.mutate()` does return a function with a single integer property. It's supposed to return an array really.